# How to apply more than one time regexp_extract funtion in hive sql

Tags: sql, database, string, split, hive

I have a query like this:

```
select 
name,
split(name, ' ')[0] as name_1
from table
```

Which I wish to apply twice a regular expression, is it possible?

What I have done and it has not worked is:

```
select 
name,
split(name, ' ')[0] as name_1,
split(regexp_extract(name, "^(.*?)\\s(.*)",2), ' ')[0] as name_1,
from table
```

If I had:
Name: Mark Bill Gates Potter
The expected result will be: Gates Potter

Address: Gate 294 st. 1.4 Arizona
Expected: st. 1.4 Arizona

Name column is the full name (eg. Mark Bill Gates Potter), my idea is to keep the 3rd word until the finish sentence (eg. Gates Potter). How would this be possible?

Im working in Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my idea is to keep the 3rd word until the finish sentence (eg. Gates Potter)

That could be:

```
split(name, ' ')[2] || ' ' || split(name, ' ')[3] as name_3_4
```

If you really want everything from the third word, a regex is better:

```
regexp_replace(name, '^\\S+\\s*\\S+\\s*', '') as name_3_and_more
```

The idea here replace the first two words with the empty string.

Comment: How it could be if the strings are variable? I mean, sometimes will be data with 5 words instead 4 strings

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question, what if I wanted to extract the numbers in the last regexp_replace you have done?

Comment: @SebastianHanania: parsing addresses is tricky. If that's what you want, then I would recommend asking *a new question*, along with a clear problem statement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. I have made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417481/how-to-apply-more-than-one-time-funtions-in-select-statement-hive-sql